# What is the proper way to initialize a ComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-warnings, jcombobox

Here's what I've been using.

```
String[] entryUniqueDescAry;                   // <--declared statement
entryUniqueDescAry = new String[theEntries.size()];
int i = 0;
for(Entry e : theEntries){
    entryUniqueDescAry[i] = e.GetUniqueDescription();
    i++;
}
cboConcoursEntry.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(entryUniqueDescAry));
```

This produces:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to DefaultComboBoxModel(E[]) as a member of the raw type DefaultComboBoxModel
        cboConcoursEntry.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(entryUniqueDescAry));
```

Where E is a type-variable:

```
    E extends Object declared in class DefaultComboBoxModel
```

I know the warning can be ignored, but it would ease my conscience if I could make it go away. How do I fix it?

Comment: 20 people watch the [tag:jcombobox] tag. The [tag:java] tag has 1.9 million. I added the latter tag as well as two other tags that seem relevant. Maybe this will get some attention now, or at least more than the [checks] 11 times it has been viewed so far.

Comment: A `JComboBox` `DefaultComboBoxModel` can accept any Java object.  The `String` from the `toString` method is displayed in the GUI.  If you're passing `Strings` to the `DefaultComboBoxModel`, define it as a `DefaultComboBoxModel<String>` and `JComboBox<String>`, respectively.